# How do Resource Governer changes take effect after being set?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Will I need to reboot my server or will it pick up the changes and start encorcing it on the fly?

Will existing long running queries be affected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only applies to new connections once you enable it. It *does not* affect existing connections.

To take effect on new connections, no, you shouldn't have to restart the instance.

Also, note that actual resource *governing* only kicks in when there is contention for a resource (i.e., CPU).